# how to specify path with space inside file in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, cd

**cat ~/.last_dir**

```
/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/Desktop/main project/backup/main project 2
```

**cd `cat ~/.last_dir`**

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

I tried using backslash inside the file

```
/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/Desktop/main\ project/backup/main\ project\ 2
```

Still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the results of expanding `cat ...`:

```
cd "$(cat ~/.last_dir)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd "$(<~/.last_dir)"
```

First, put quotes **around** the `$(...)` to make the space part of the filename.
Second, `$(<...)` is a `bash` construct that reads the file directly without executing `cat`, but is not entirely portable.

For a more generic, less bash-specific version, use Maxim's solution.

Answer (score 0):

just put quotation marks around your path:

```
"/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/OneDrive/Desktop/main project/backup/main project 2"
```

this should work for most cases